# Isotope and Knockout js having trouble removing dynamically added elements

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-isotope

I've been trying to get Isotopejs and Knockoutjs to work together. So, far Its been working swimmingly except for when I need to add elements to the dom and then need to remove them.

I've traced the problem down to inside this method:
ko.utils.setDomNodeChildrenFromArrayMapping = function (domNode, array, mapping, options, callbackAfterAddingNodes) { .. }

Which is calling this method
fixUpVirtualElements(lastMappingResult[lastMappingResultIndex].domNodes);

The fixUpVirtualElements method is removing the dom node that I need to remove w/ isotope in the beforeRemove event; The foreach binding calls is not getting the element that needs to be removed.

I've read the notes for that method in knockout.. but I dont understand what they mean because I dont have any domain knowledge for what its talking about.

Can anyone please take a look at my latest jsfiddle and let me know why fixUpVirutalElements is removing the element I need to be passed to the beforeRemove event.

http://jsfiddle.net/evanlarsen/C5y6G/

Can someone please fix this jsFiddle to get the 2 librarys working together.

Thanks,
Evan Larsen

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue with adding or removing, they are both working in the fiddle. What is the issue you are having? BTW I really like this +1

Comment: when i add new elements to the list then i try and remove those new elements.. the new elements wont get removed. atleast thats whats happening to me, and im using IE9 and latest Chrome

Comment: Oh, yes new elements wont remove. Sorry, I only tried removing two items and they were both original

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not an expert of isotope; I know just what it does but I have no knowledge of its algorithms, however I have an indeep knowledge of the sources of knockout.js. Now probably the problem is that isotope manipulate the dom nodes created by knockout template binding. knockout.js DO NOT ALLOW THAT OTHER PROGRAMS TOUCH THE DOM NODES CREATED BY TEMPLATES. All knockout.js algorithms assume that the only way dom nodes created by templates are changed is by manipulating the array bound to the template. If something else manipulate directly that nodes, either by adding nodes, removing nodes or (as in the case of isotope) reordering them..all knockout js algorithm go crazy...this means deleted nodes doesn't disappear, some nodes are duplicated...and so on.

------------------------update----------------

SOLVED
just substitute:

```
self.serviceAdded = function(el) {
        if (el && el.nodeType === 1) {
           $('#container').isotope('insert', $(el)); 

        }
    };
```

with:

```
self.serviceAdded = function(el) {
        if (el && el.nodeType === 1) {
           $('#container').isotope('appended', $(el)); 

        }
    };
```

Comment: If you step through the jsfiddle you will see that isotope doesnt re-order the nodes in the dom. It just applys css transformations to them and sets them to absolute positioning.  Thats how it does its animation and what appears to the user as re-ordering.

Comment: This open the possibility for a solution. Still this way during updates of the arrays elements can be destroyed and recreated. When they are created again the will loose all settings applied by isotope.
Destroy +recreation of the same element happens substantially in two circumstances: 1) you move an element from one place to another in the array this cause deletion + recreation in the new place 2) due to some computables or dependecies  all elements bound to the array may be destroyed an created again. Often the last problem can be fixed. I will give a better  look to your code

Comment: Probably found the problem. Thwe isotope "remove" method first just filter out the element but then it actually remove it from the dom. YOU MUST JUST FILTER OUT the the element in the beforeRemove function and you must let knockout detach it from the dom..otherwise knockout is not able to track anymore all changes

Comment: Upon creating a new element in the dom w/ knockout and registering that new element w/ isotope it is doing something funky.  So, that when the beforeRemove event is called.. knockout is not passing the dom element to the beforeRemove event.  I'm not sure the reasoning but if knockout just passed the dom element to the beforeRemove event then I would imagine everything would work fine.

Comment: This means after the add knockout data structures are already dirty. In fact the "isnert" isotope method not only do CSS stuffs but add also the element to the container. Now consider thatt when the afterAdd method is appled the element has already been added to the container by knockout, so...triing to add it again create a problem. You should simply call the append method. I tried this and it now works!!! I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been banging my head on this problem for days.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best option for combining Isotope and Knockout is through a binding for the latter. To that end, I've written one called [Knockout-Isotope](https://github.com/aknuds1/knockout-isotope). Mind that it requires a forked version of [Knockout](https://github.com/aknuds1/knockout), but hopefully the minor changes I've made can be integrated back at some point.

As I've just finished Knockout-Isotope, it isn't super well tested, but it handles the scenarios I've thrown at it so far at least.

### Code

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/fHW3t/).

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Knockout Isotope Binding Demo</h1>
<p>This is a demonstration of the 
 <a href="https://github.com/aknuds1/knockout-isotope">Knockout-Isotope</a>
 binding for <a href="http://knockoutjs.com/">Knockout</a>, which visualizes
 Knockout observableArrays through
 <a href="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html">Isotope</a>.
</p>

<p>Click on an item to remove it or click in the item container to add a new item</p>
<div id="container" data-bind="isotope: { data: items, isotopeOptions: getOptions }, click: addItem">
  <div data-bind="text: text, click: $parent.removeItem, clickBubble: false"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function ItemModel(parent) {
    var value, self = this,
        found, i;
    for (value = 0; value < parent.items().length; ++value) {
        found = false;
        for (i in parent.items()) {
            var item = parent.items()[i];
            if (item.value() == value) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            break;
        }
    }
    this.value = ko.observable(value);

    this.text = ko.computed(function () {
        return "Item " + self.value();
    });
}

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.items.push(new ItemModel(self));
    self.items.push(new ItemModel(self));

    this.removeItem = function (item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    };

    this.addItem = function () {
        self.items.push(new ItemModel(self));
    };

    // Knockout callback for getting Isotope options
    this.getOptions = function () {
        return {
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: 210
            }
        };
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Test"));
```